# Multiple terms in one filter

Tags: views

I am passing multiple tags into an exposed field separated by a comma. If a single tag doesn't have a result, it ruins the entire view.

Is there a way to treat the extra tags as optional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use '+' to separate the tags instead of ','. The '+' is used for "OR" while the ',' is used for "AND".

Here is a screenshot from the Views administrative interface:

[image: The Views UI for multiple arguments]